# Error in the looping that made an infinite loop of (*)

Tags: c

This is the program to find mean, median, and mode of element in array and then make histogram from it,

but the problem i have is only at the star count and print the star

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sample[50] = {4,3,5,5,1,5,5,5,4,3,5,3,3,5,5,5,2,5,5,5,5,4,3,5,5,2,5,2,5,4,3,5,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,4,3,5,3,3,5,5,5,};

    int i;
    int j;
    int f1;
    int f2;
    int f3;
    int f4;
    int f5;
    int temp;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int median;
    float mean;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    if(sample[i] == 1)
    {
        f1++;
    }
    else if(sample[i] == 2)
    {
        f2++;   
    }
    else if(sample[i] == 3)
    {
        f3++;
    }
    else if(sample[i] == 4)
    {
        f4++;
    }
    else if(sample[i] == 5)
    {
        f5++;
    }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t", i + 1);
        if(i == 0)
        {
        printf(" %d\t", f1);
        for(j = 0; j < f1; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
        printf(" %d\t", f2);
        for(j = 0; j < f2; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
        printf(" %d\t", f3);
        for(j = 0; j < f3; j++)
        {
        printf("*");
        }
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
        printf(" %d\t", f4);
        for(j = 0; j < f4; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
        printf(" %d\t", f5);
        for(j = 0; j < f5; j++);
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

**[The output should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcDb9.png)**

but

**[My output right now is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAVa7.png)**

it seems the loop happened because the frequency of number 4 is 4205314, so the star looped until that number, but i can't find why the frequency goes that high

Comment: First step is to indent your code correctly. There is no way you can figure out what happens (and neither can we) if your code is unreadable.

Comment: But without indentation, it is visible that `f1`, `f2`, ... are unitialized. So, they contain purely random number, negative or positive. And `++` them as much as you want still let those number random

Comment: As @chrslg said, with your poor code indentation, it's pretty much impossible to follow the execution path of your code. Fix that so that it's at least readable, and then step through the code in the debugger to find your logic error. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. There is no better tool available to a coder to track down logic errors, and it's never too early to start learning to use that tool.

Comment: You set `int count = 0;`, and then loop until `count`:  `for(i = 0; i < count; i++)`.  How many times do you expect that for loop to run like that??

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler and shorter way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    static const int sample[50] = {4,3,5,5,1,5,5,5,4,3,5,3,3,5,5,5,2,5,5,5,5,4,3,5,5,2,5,2,5,4,3,5,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,4,3,5,3,3,5,5,5,};
    int count = sizeof(sample)/sizeof(*sample);    
    int histo[5] = {};
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        histo[sample[i]-1]++;
    }
    
    char stars[count];
    ((char*)memset(stars, '*', count))[count-1] = '\0';
    
    printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", "Response", "Frequency", "Histogram");
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%-20d%-20d%.*s\n", i+1, histo[i], histo[i], stars);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5500KB
Response            Frequency           Histogram           
1                   1                   *
2                   3                   ***
3                   12                  ************
4                   5                   *****
5                   29                  *****************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your variables are uninitialized, and are likely completely random numbers. You then reference those random numbers in your for loops which is why they are not behaving how you indented them to.

You need to initialize your variables to the value you expect them to start at, for example:

```c
int f1 = 0, f2 = 0, f3 = 0, f4 = 0, f5 = 0;
```